# How to set the view-port width and height programmatically on a Android webview

Tags: android, webview, embed

I am using the Android webview to embed youtube and vimeo players. When the player plays the native controls of the HTML5 videoplayer appear but scale with the size of the pixels of the device.

On a Samsung S3 this means very small controls. Is there a way to set the view-port programmatically from Android? I have tried to fiddle around with these WebSettings but didn't manage to get the controls to appear bigger:

```
getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.setInitialScale(0);
```

I am using API level 19 as target SDK.